# Applying sorting on datareader while binding to dropdown in asp

Tags: c#, sorting, drop-down-menu, datareader

Currently I am facing a problem for sorting `datareader` contents alphabetically. The scenario is I have a `datareader` that reads department name from database. Then, in while loop, I am binding each `datareader` row to dropdown (`<select><option Value=''>Some Text</option></select>`). I want to show contents in alphabetical order.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: offcourse i am serious about getting answers to my questions.While i post a question then at the sametime i try at my end to find solution. I think according to you i have to mention, if i get exact solution to my qustion. Since i post my question, i am doing rnd to find solution at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do anything with a datareader besides looping through the records.  You'll need to apply the sort to your source query.

If you get the data into a DataTable, you can apply the sort before binding.

Answer (score 1):

How are you retrieving the values from the database? Can't you just add an Order By clause to your query?

Comment: <%If drdDepartment.HasRows = True Then
    While Not drdDepartment.Read = False%>
     <option value="<%=drdDepartment("Department_Code")%>" <%If drdDepartment("Department_Code") = GetRequestItem("UsersTextSearch") Then%> selected <%End if%>>
      <%=drdDepartment("Department_Name")%>
     </option>
    <%End While%> 
   <%End If
    drdDepartment.Close()

Comment: How do you populate drdDepartment with it's records. If your using a SQL query to pull the data from the DB, you should be able to add an "Order By DepartmentName ASC" to the end of you SQL.

Comment: ok i have figured out my problem's solution, when i use order by clause on sql server end, it solved my issue. Thanks a lot for your help and consideration. Really this forum is very helpful for me..